# PHP preg_match not working. How to resolve?

Tags: php

```
$Query = 'ઋષભ';
if (!preg_match('/\x{0A80}-\x{0AFF}/u', $Query)){
    echo 'English';
}
else{
    echo 'Gujarati';
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why the preg_match function is not working How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

To match a character range you have to put it in `[]`.

```
$Query = 'ઋષભ';
if (!preg_match('/[\x{0A80}-\x{0AFF}]/u', $Query)){
    echo 'English';
}
else{
    echo 'Gujarati';
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/981276